# a query to compare data from two tables A AND B and give the results as per table A

Tags: sql

I have a list of phone numbers that am sending messages to. in table `A` I record all the delivery status of each number. 
I created another table `B` and stored some contacts in it. 
I want an SQL query that I can use to compare the data in `A` and `B` such that, I want to get delivery status of numbers in table `B` from table `A`. If a number is appearing in the table `A` and `B` then I get the delivery status of that number.

I am using this SQL query:

```
SELECT address, delivery_status FROM safaricom_receipt
WHERE address IN (SELECT mobile FROM saf_dispute);
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: An `EXISTS` or `INNER JOIN` could replace the `IN`. But wouldn't the current query already give the expected results? So why the question?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Explain why your query does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :

```
SELECT address, delivery_status 
FROM safaricom_receipt 
INNER JOIN saf_dispute 
ON safaricom_receipt.address=saf_dispute.mobile;
```

Comment: That returns something different. When you replace an IN condition with a JOIN you are changing the meaning of the query

Comment: As per his statement : "If a number is appearing in the table A and B then I get the delivery status of that number" this is the case of join. So I used JOIN instead.

Comment: But if the number appears twice you will see the row twice which does not happen with an IN condition.

Comment: No, with IN as well we will get two records, if that is specified in IN.

Comment: It would depend on how many rows per number are being stored in the table which hold the delivery_status

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server; this should work for you

```
SELECT sd.mobile, sr.delivery_status 
FROM saf_dispute sd with (nolock)
LEFT OUTER JOIN safaricom_receipt sr with (nolock) on sd.mobile=sr.address
where sr.delivery_status is NOT NULL
```

you would get duplicate rows if you are storing multiple rows for the same mobile number in any table. I would suggest adding a datetime column in the future

Comment: Why the `NOLOCK`? And how do you know Pascal is using SQL Server?

Comment: It was my assumption since it was not mentioned which product the OP is using